# What means this Grails-error: "Cannot read write-only property: emptyStringsToNull"?

Tags: grails

In a grails-program I get the following exception:

```
Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot read write-only property: emptyStringsToNull
    at geoway.catalogue.controller.CswController$_closure1.doCall(CswController.groovy:19)
    at geoway.catalogue.controller.CswController$_closure1.doCall(CswController.groovy)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

At this point in the code, I can find the following line:

```
redirect(action:list,params:params)
```

The whole project doesn't contain a string 'emptyStringsToNull'. How do I find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without any code snippet, but try to put action name into quotes:

```
redirect(action: "list", params: params)
```